# android using class annotation,getting anotation from child,decleare anotation in parent

Tags: reflection, annotations, parent, extend, children

i have some classes that they are using annotation to fetch data from db.
for example my test table is like:

```
public 
@Table(name="test",isNamesLikeDB=true)
@Communicator(getMySelf="gettest",getOurSelf="gettestList",sendMySelf="updatetest",sendOurSelf="updatetestList")
class test_ extends Model{
public 
@ID
@Expose
@SerializedName("Gid")
@Column(name="Gid")
String Gid;
public 
@Expose
@SerializedName("Fname")
@Column(name="Fname")
String Fname;
public 
@Expose
@SerializedName("LocalID")
@Column(name="LocalID")
int LocalID = -1;
}
```

Table annotation:

```
@Target(java.lang.annotation.ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Table {
    public String name();
    public boolean isNamesLikeDB();
}
```

and my model class:

```
public abstract class Model {
    boolean loadResult = false;
    private boolean HasID = false;
    private boolean HasValue = false;
    private Manager manager=new Manager();
    public boolean load() {
        loadResult = false;
        Table table = getClass().getAnnotation(Table.class);
        if (table != null) {
            String whereStatment = "";
            Field fields[] = getClass().getDeclaredFields();
            boolean morethan1Id = false;
            for (Field field : fields) {
                Column col = field.getAnnotation(Column.class);
                ID fid = field.getAnnotation(ID.class);
                boolean findId = false;
                String column = "";
                if (col != null) {
                    column = col.name();
                }
                if (fid != null) {
                    findId = true;
                }
                if (findId) {
                    if (morethan1Id)
                        whereStatment += " and " + column + "="
                                + getfieldString(field,this) + " ";
                    else
                        whereStatment += "where " + column + "="
                                + getfieldString(field,this) + " ";
                    morethan1Id = true;
                }
            }
            Cursor c = DataSourceTools.findAllObject("select * from "
                    + table.name() + " " + whereStatment);
            if (c!=null&&c.moveToFirst())
                loadResult = filFromCursor(c, this);
            else
                loadResult = false;
            setHasID(loadResult);
            setHasValue(loadResult);
            return loadResult;
        }
        throw new NullPointerException(
                "you must declear table annotation for your class");
    }
}



public class test1 extends test_{
}
```

when i create another class like test1 that it extends test class i want Table annotation be accessible in test1,and no more define Table annotation for class test1 when i use this code:

```
new test1().load();
```

when i call load() method it runs load method in model class,and in model class the first thing is getting Table Annotation.

```
getClass().getAnnotation(Table.class);
```

this line returns null,but i declare table annotation for test,anyone can help me?(sorry for my bad English)

Answer (score -1):

I solved it with this code:

```
getClass().getSuperClass().getAnnotation(Table.class);
```